# Why am I getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column ...." here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Getting the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table
>   'master.dbo.Problems'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

on my table created with

```
CREATE TABLE Problems ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    prompt_code VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

after I try to run the basic command

```
INSERT INTO Problems (prompt_code) VALUES ( '<span>Blah blah blah</span>' );
```

What gives?

Comment: Have you run any other commands or changed any other settings on your DB?  Is `IDENTITY_INSERT` on?  I can't reproduce this with your supplied script (the insert runs fine)

Comment: Your code works fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1db8d.

Comment: Have you used `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for that table recently? I don't recall if that shuts off the identity or just allows you to insert with an explicit value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I cannot check your SQL fiddle, it returns error when I tried `select * from Problems`

Comment: Do you have an `instead of` trigger on the table? @TomH it does disable it, but a different error would be generated - `Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Problems' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON`

Comment: Why are you using the `Master` database?

Comment: Actually, `IDENTITY_INSERT` shouldn't affect it, you'd get a different error (`Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Problems' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.`)

Comment: @Fred points - maybe - a solution: Maybe in master-db there is a relict of a former try to create your table (that time without the identity) and your insert points accidentily to the wrong database - but strangely seems to work... Anyway. That what you have written, should work for sure...

Comment: btw: You should name your constraints. Later upgrades via script will be a real pain in the neck otherwise... `... created DATETIME CONSTRAINT DF_Problems_Created DEFAULT ...` Same with Primary Key...

Comment: Do you have more than one Problems table.  If you amend the query to *INSERT INTO Master.dbo.Problems...* do you still get the same error?